# Python wav format parsing: Non-standard data frame output

Tags: python, parsing, hex, output, wav

I am baffled by erroneous hexadecimal output from some WAV files that I am parsing. My question is: How do I interpret and/or correct for the abnormal data frames in the sample shown below?

I am using the Python standard library to read the data frames from the WAV file.

A sample input/output from IDLE of twelve sample frame printouts, along with my notation to the right, is as follows:

Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 13:52:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

```
>>> import wave
>>> sound = wave.open("/Users/Fergus_Home/Desktop/DmytroK.wav",mode = None)
>>> sound.setpos(100000)
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'\x15\xff\x15\xff'     #<----Clearly hexadecimal
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'\xfd\xfe\xfd\xfe'
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'\xdc\xfe\xdc\xfe'
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'\xbc\xfe\xbc\xfe'
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'\x9b\xfe\x9b\xfe'
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'\x88\xfe\x88\xfe'
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'}\xfe}\xfe'          #<------- Corrupted? Compressed? Junk data/padding? 
                       #Text editor interpreting a hexadecimal as a character? 
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'g\xfeg\xfe'          #<------- ???
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'N\xfeN\xfe'          #<------- ???
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b';\xfe;\xfe'          #<------- ???
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b"'\xfe'\xfe"          #<------- ???
>>> sound.readframes(1) 
b'\x0f\xfe\x0f\xfe'    #<----Clearly hexadecimal
```

Make note:

1) The first pair of hexadecimal groups form the left channel, and the second pair form the right channel.  So in the first frame the left channel hexadecimal sample is 15 FF, and the right channel hexadecimal is also 15 FF.

2) WAV files are in little endian format by default.  This means that the most significant bits are being preserved in the irregular printouts.  The least significant bits are the ones being replaced by characters.

3) Queries indicate that the data is not compressed.

4) I have found the same issue with Python's standard library for parsing AIFF files.  This also happens with other sound recordings from various devices.

Any thoughts on what is happening to the least significant bits in each frame printout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is simply the ASCII representation of the 4-byte frames.

```
>>> len(b'}\xfe}\xfe')
4
>>> b'}\xfe}\xfe' == b'\x7d\xfe\x7d\xfe'
True
>>> b'\x7d\xfe\x7d\xfe'
b'}\xfe}\xfe'
>>> b'}' == b'\x7d'
True
>>> b'g' == b'\x67'
True
>>> b'N' == b'\x4e'
True
>>> b';' == b'\x3b'
True
>>> b"'" == b'\x27'
True
```

But perhaps `binascii` would give you a better representation:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'\x7d\xfe\x7d\xfe')
b'7dfe7dfe'
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'}\xfe}\xfe')
b'7dfe7dfe'
```

Comment: Thank you, cpburnz!  I suspected that something like this was the case.  In your opinion, is this likely a consequence of the text editor misinterpreting the data, or will I have to create a library of ASCII values to transform the 4-byte frames into their proper format?

Comment: @user3830794 This is not indicative of a problem at all. The editor is interpreting the data properly. This is merely how python displays the representation of bytes.

Comment: This makes sense.  Therefore, the only reason why all of the other 4-byte frames retain their hexadecimal values is because they do not have an ASCII equivalent?

Comment: @user3830794 Precisely. Also, ASCII control characters will be displayed as hexadecimal.